# How can I add one row for each group in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

My current df looks like that

| Region | Descript | Material | Input |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| UK | Bottle | #1 | 500 |
| UK | Cap | #5 | 20 |
| India | Bottle | #1 | 400 |
| India | Cap | #5 | 2 |

would like to have a df2 to be like:

| Region | Descript | Material | Input |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| UK | Bottle | #1 | 500 |
| UK | Cap | #5 | 20 |
| UK | other | #7 | NA |
| India | Bottle | #1 | 400 |
| India | Cap | #5 | 2 |
| India | other | #7 | NA |

I am new to python. Maybe there is a simple solution or an already similar case but i couldn't find anything

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`groupby.tail`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.tail.html) to get the last row of each group, and modify them with [`assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html), then [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) it to the original DataFrame and sort by index while resetting it:

```
out = pd.concat([df,
                 df.groupby('Region', sort=False, as_index=False).tail(1)
                   .assign(Descript='other', Material='#7', Input='NA')]
               ).sort_index(ignore_index=True)
```

Output:

```
  Region Descript Material Input
0     UK   Bottle       #1   500
1     UK      Cap       #5    20
2     UK    other       #7    NA
3  India   Bottle       #1   400
4  India      Cap       #5     2
5  India    other       #7    NA
```

Comment: One little thing: ...Input='NA'))]..one parenthesis was missing

Comment: Thanks @John, fixed it (you can actually remove the parentheses) ;)